# ReactJS, Jest, Enzyme: CORS error - Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden - any hints to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, fetch, enzyme

Attempting to fetch image inside test to then test upload to cloudinary, weird thing is it worked a few times, now getting CORS error described. Any hints?

```
test('debe cargar un archivo y retornar el URL', async () => {
const res = await fetch(
      'https://www.ideaseinventos.es/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/tiburon.jpg',
);

const blob = await res.blob();
const file = new File([blob], 'foto.png');

const url = await fileUpload(file);

expect(typeof url).toBe('string');

// borrar imagen
const segments = url.split('/');
const imageId = segments[segments.length - 1].replace('.png', '');

const { deleted } = await cloudinary.v2.api.delete_resources(imageId);
expect(deleted).toEqual({ [imageId]: 'deleted' });
  });
```